# creating ipa for distribution to client

Tags: ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile

I wanted to know what is the use to create an ipa and distribute it to client for testing when we can easily zip the built app and distribute the zipped .app file.

What is the benefit of creating the `.ipa`?

Is it that creating the `ipa` do not need the mobile provisioning profile?

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ipa file is in fact the installable.

I'd recommend reading the [iOS Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (see the "Distributing Applications" section in particular), as this explains everything in detail.

Comment: so that means we do need a mobile provisioning profile to build the .ipa. but then whats the advantage over .app.

Comment: @Laura If you read the above link, all should become clear. :-)

Comment: sorry to bother you, I read the whole document but I am still not getting the advantage of distributing the .ipa over distributing the .app file.

Comment: @Laura The key difference is the the .ipa file contains the .app plus other information (app store icons, etc.) The .ipa file is effectively the package that delivers the app if that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I would tell you an advantage from my experience. When you deliver a zipped .app file to a client, if he is using iTunes on  Windows machine, he would be tempted to open it(as .app looks like a folder in Windows). That would actually render the app unusable. However IPA file can't be opened in any way. So it is safe to distribute IPA without considering whether it is going to be deployed on a Mac or a Windows PC.

Answer (score 4):

Although middaparka's answer has been marked as correct, the link in his answer is now deprecated. The updated reference is [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I use the .ipa over .app is because you can have your clients install your adhoc build straight from the iDevice over mobile safari without having to go through iTunes.

This comes in VERY handy.  However, it does take some research to do because it is a wee bit tedious. Basically you have to have a html page incorporating a link to a manifest.plist that has a link to the .ipa file.

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Build and Archive` command in `Build` menu. Then you can save it to disk as an `ipa` archive.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to send the mobile provisionning profile with the .ipa so it's easier to install for your client. And it's easier to build it (Product->Archive in Xcode than share than give the .ipa name).

I don't understand why Apple gives the technic for the .app in the iOs provisionning portal.

Comment: I think that this is incorrect. In the link referenced above (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html), it says:
In the Finder, drag the provisioning profile (the file with the .mobileprovision extension) to the iTunes icon in the Dock.
Double-click the application archive <Application_Name>.ipa.
The application appears in the iTunes Applications list. ...

Comment: What is wrong ? The .mobileprovision is not useful to install a .ipa. I'm sure about that since I use this technic for a year now. Did you try what I was saying ?

Comment: No, I did not. I'm just pointing out that the Apple documentation on the topic says to install the provisioning profile first, then the .ipa. I have tried giving .ipa files without the profile, and that was unsuccessful. not sure how you are doing this successfully...

Comment: 1- Ask your client UDID
2- Add this UDID to your provisionnning profile
3- Click "Archive" in XCode
4- Click "Share"
5- Save the .ipa
6- Send the ipa to the client
7- Et voilà :)