# Phonegap Build: Application cannot run on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Building application with Phonegap Build, but i don't know why the application couldn't install on iOS devices. I did signed the application as distribution license of Apple iOS Developer License, and here is the link for the application.

[Link to download iOS version](http://s3.amazonaws.com/ios.phonegap/slicehost-production/apps/168868/12Gain.ipa)

[Link to download Android version](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/168868/download/android)

Error i get: Can download and installing, at the middle of installation: "AppName" could not be installed at this time.

Comment: Links r not working. Could u paste the error, that u got anything...

Comment: @TrackRuler Sorry, http://s3.amazonaws.com/ios.phonegap/slicehost-production/apps/168868/12Gain.ipa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the build setting make sure you code signing identity is set to Developer and not Distribution.  Only set it to Distribution when you are going submit to iTunes

you must have an apple developer login and the appropriate provisioning and the device you install the app on must be registered in the provisioning portal.

you can go to https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action

and login with you apple developer login to make sure the device is registered in the provision portal.

Comment: i was added the device to Apple provision portal but it could not be installed also...

Comment: When I get weird build errors i usually do a project clean and delete all the files in my build directory.  then try and do an install. but my research on this error points to a provision profile issue...I can keep digging if this doesn't work

Comment: will this because of i build the application using phonegap build service and got some different ?

Comment: i doubt that it is a phonegap issue.  phonegap issues will usually cause build errors. it is an xcode provisioning profile issue.   Have you ever been able to get any other apps to run? native or phonegap?

Comment: usually i develop native app through XCode and this is the first time i use PhoneGap Built while it sound interesting.. and aware of annoying provisioning issues, i did setting properly and it still couldn't be installed on iOS

Comment: I've build several native and phonegap apps and never encountered that.   are you building the ipa and then installing it to your device or are building in debug mode straight to your device?

Comment: Yea.. i found the problem finally.. cannot use debug mode for the iOS application...

Answer (score 0):

Build your `Phonegap` app for `iOS` just as you would a native one. That's the biggest advantage of using `Phonegap` - you have all the control. Add the devices you want to test to a provisioning profile, add the profile to organizer, set the code signing identity to that profile and then archive/build your app, etc. You can refer to the various links available online like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861891/creating-ipa-for-distribution-to-client) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817162/create-ipa-file-in-xcode-4-2-ios-5-0-beta). My guess is that you forgot to add the UDIDs of the devices you want to test on to the provisioning profile that you've used. Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222946/how-to-find-out-what-profile-was-used-for-building-ipa-file/10223230#10223230) to see if you had added these devices to the provisioning profile.