# Test iOS on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, testing

I am already testing my iOS app on my iPhone and it works great. My client wants to test my app on his own device but the problem is that he is a resident of different country. Can I send him something like we have "apk" in Android?

Comment: IPA files are packaged app bundles. He won't be able to install it though, unless he has the appropeiate provisioning profile on his device, or if it's jailbroken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the "Ad-hoc".Steps:

Add Your partner's device to the iOS provisioning portal at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
Generate a provisioning profile that includes it for your app.
Build the app using this profile.
[Generate an .IPA file](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html) using `Product->Archive`
Send it to your partner that .IPA file.
Many more details available in [Apple's guides under "Ad-Hoc" testing.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

This is also a good option. [testflightapp.com](https://testflightapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send him IPA file.

See here:[creating ipa for distribution to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861891/creating-ipa-for-distribution-to-client)

OR

you can refer to this link: [How to make .ipa file in Xcode 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969917/how-to-make-ipa-file-in-xcode-4-5)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into services such as [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) to make the process of publishing and installing the app on your client's machine.  Get your ad hoc provisional profile and archive your build.  TestFlight will upload it to their servers and email your client that the build is ready.  From there the installation is a snap.

Answer (score 0):

Just send an .IPA File to him he cant see the code using that